# How to convert VDC to VAC at a high frequency?

Tags: electrical-engineering, ac

How to convert 10 VDC to VAC at a high frequency, say 10 MHz? VACpp can be +-10V or +-5V.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Maybe this would be a better match for Electrical Engineering SE.

Comment: @qwe  What do you need the 10 MHz for?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You want something called a *oscillator*.  It is powered from DC, and produces AC output, usually a sine or square wave.  For the case of 10 MHz, you can use a resonant design since the components can be physically small.  RF transmitters are examples of circuits that take DC power in and AC at a specific frequency at substantial power.